# xslt transform to combine child nodes into a string

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have some xml that looks something like this:

```
<Lists>
<ListA>
    <Item
        name = "Name1"
        ID = "ID1"
        shoesize = "10">
       <AddressList>
           <Enum>City1</Enum>
           <Enum>City2</Enum>
       </AddressList>
    </Item>
    <Item
        name = "Name2"
        ID = "ID2"
        shoesize = "13">
       <AddressList>
           <Enum>City3</Enum>
       </AddressList>
    </Item>
</ListA>
<ListB>
    ...
</ListB>
</Lists>
```

I need a transform that selects only the Items in ListA and produces a single line of pipe-separated text per item, but also flattens out the addresses into a semicolon separated list like this:

```
Name1|ID1|City1;City2
Name2|ID2|City3
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="Item"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>|<xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't know how to loop over the AddressList and put it into a single field. I'd also like to ignore ListB.

I'm sure this is basic stuff but I don't know xslt and everything I've read seems to assume a certain knowledge... plus I can't find a quick beginners guide that gives me enough to work this out.

Comment: Please post a **well-formed** input example - one that has a single root element and no spaces in element names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a **well-formed** input, such as:

**XML**

```
<root>
   <ListA>
      <Item name="Name1" ID="ID1" shoesize="10">
         <AddressList>
            <Enum>City1</Enum>
            <Enum>City2</Enum>
         </AddressList>
      </Item>
      <Item name="Name2" ID="ID2" shoesize="13">
         <AddressList>
            <Enum>City3</Enum>
         </AddressList>
      </Item>
   </ListA>
   <ListB>
    ...
   </ListB>
</root>
```

you could use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ListA"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="AddressList/Enum">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce:

```
Name1|ID1|City1;City2
Name2|ID2|City3
```